# notify installation complete from service

Tags: android, service, installation, status, notify

I have this piece of code

```
private void initiateInstallation() { 

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/example.apk")); 
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

that from within my service installs an application named example.apk

I want after the installation is finished to run an activity which notifies the user about the installation.I did that except the activity appears before the installation finishes.
The problem is that within a service I cannot use startActivityForResult. So, I need a way around this so that I can start my notification activity(or for the sake of example just print something out with Toast within the service) only AFTER the installation is complete. 
I already tried some answers from other questions like "alternative to startActivityforResult in services" but still I couldn't figure this out. 
I also put the code so that maybe there may be something done in there.

Thanks in advance ... any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast intent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

As far as I know, these are sent after the installation is done, and you can listen to those from the service.

Just note that if the application was already installed, you will get ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED (as far as I know).

Also you must know the package name as well, not just the apk name, since the intent will contain the package name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Pal Szasz is technically correct (as far as I know ;-) ).

However, based on the information given in your question, I assume you only wish to show a notification (no further programmatically actions are to be performed). If my assumptions are correct I would respectfully advise you **NOT** to show such a notification. And this is why:

The Android system already has a standard means of passing notifications to the user. The status bar will in this case already show you a message saying that the new app is successfully installed (or not installed in case of an error). If you implement yet another notification channel you will most likely confuse or irritate your users by diverging from the standard, expected behaviour.

Taking this beyond the borders of sanity one could also argue for the fact that you in some sense also would contribute to the fragmentation of Android (in a very small scale, but nevertheless).